# How can I not change the screen orientation if the device rotates (Browser only)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a big React JS project with several modules. I have written some Javascript code to detect the screen's width and loading the components. When a user changes the device orientation, UI is breaking in most of the cases (Eg: Ipad).

On internet, I've found out some solutions like changing CSS for those screen sizes. But it is difficult for me. 
Some solutions like writing CSS files in meta tags for the specific orientation. This is a big project. How can I do that?

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
}

onWindowResize = e => {
  // I want to open a modal without changing the orientation here
  e.preventDefault(); // Not working
  e.stopPropagation(); // Not working
  alert('Alert! Your screen size altered.');
  // The problem here is the screen size changed and then it is showing the alert. I don't want to change it.
};
```

The solution I'm looking for is,
I will through a pop-up asking for the user's confirmation
1) You have to refresh for better user-experience (it can be done)
2) You will be on the same screen-orientation

Comment: You don't even need to use js to detect screen sizes, you can just simply use css media queries. Here's a good source that explains how to use them: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: You don't even need to use js to detect screen sizes, you can just simply use css media queries. Here's a good source that explains how to use them: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you @Ari But it doesn't solve my problem. I am loading components based on the screen's width which are plain Javascript. It won't get triggered when the screen size gets changed.

Comment: what exactly happens when the screen rotates ? do you have an url or a working jsfiddle to share ?

Comment: I don't have a working example. I just want to block from rotating. I have searched something like screen.orientation.lock() but it is not supported across all the browsers.